# Dependency between struct field values in Rust

Tags: rust

I have the following Rust struct:

```rust
struct Binary<'a> {
    path: PathBuf,
    bytes: Vec<u8>,
    pe: PE<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Binary<'a> {
    fn read(p: PathBuf) -> Binary<'a> {
        todo!();
    }
}
```

Here `PE` comes from the [goblin crate](https://docs.rs/goblin/latest/goblin/pe/struct.PE.html).

I've tried a few things to implement the `read` function, but I'm struggling with the dependency between the `bytes` field and the `PE` that is referencing those bytes:

For instance:

```
fn new(p: PathBuf) -> Binary<'a> {
        if let Ok(bytes) = std::fs::read(&p) {
            Binary {
                path: p,
                bytes: bytes,
                pe: PE::parse(&bytes).unwrap()
            }
        } else {
            panic!()
        }
}
```

Obviously that doesn't work, `bytes` is borrowed after it has been moved at the `bytes: bytes` line. I don't see a way to initialize the PE field from the moved value of the bytes field.

Currently I've worked around it by not storing the `PE` in the `Binary` struct and simply created a function that returns a PE from the bytes when I need it:

```rust
    fn pe(&self) -> Option<PE> {
        match PE::parse(&self.bytes) {
            Ok(p) => Some(p),
            Err(_) => None,
        }
    }
```

But I'm curious to know what I am missing and how can I parse the file only once.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to define the bytes outside of the `read` function, which works because the lifetime of the bytes is greater than the lifetime of the `binary` struct.

```
struct Binary<'a> {
    path: PathBuf,
    bytes: Vec<u8>,
    pe: PE<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Binary<'a> {
    fn read(bytes: &'a [u8], path: PathBuf) -> Result<Self, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        let pe = PE::parse(bytes)?;
        Ok(Self {
            path,
            bytes: bytes.to_vec(),
            pe,
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let path = PathBuf::from("my path");
    let bytes = std::fs::read(&path).unwrap();
    let binary = Binary::read(&bytes, path);
}
```